# Teechart labels an graph

Tags: java, android, teechart

We're building an android application with graphs in it. These graphs are generated using the teechart component. The graph is based on 32 points and displays a daynumber on the x-axis and a weight in the 0-3kg range on the y-axis.

In a line graph the labels on the x-axis look pretty nice and have a good distance between them. On the y-axis however the labels are very crammed together and the numbers are not nice round numbers.

I have already played with major en minor ticks and the increment but can't find a nice way to do this.

Does anyone have suggestions how to fix this?

Comment: Are you using the TeeChart Java for Android version or TeeChart for Xamarin.Android version?

Comment: It is the Java for Android version

Comment: Could you please add a simple code snippet to your question so that we can reproduce the problem here? Thanks in advance.